# We toss $4$ symmetrical dices $10$ times. Calculate the probability of case written down below.

Tags: probability

We toss $4$ symmetrical dices $10$ times. What is the probability that the number of toss where $1.$ and $2.$ die showed at the same time numbers that are divisible by $3$ is equal to the number of toss where $3.$ and $4.$ die showed at the same time numbers that are not divisible by $3$?

I got stuck at the beggining, because I can not think of a method for solving this. Any hint helps!

Comment: Just to confirm the event is that the numbers on first and second dices are multiples of $3$ while the numbers on third and fourth aren't multiples of $3$? Am I right?

Comment: Are you talking about ordinary $6$-sided dice?  ("Die" is the singular, "dice" is the plural).  In any event the way to start is by answering the question for a single die.  What is the probability that the number that shows up is divisible by $3$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: let $x_i^j$ be result of $i$-th die at $j$-th toss. Number of $j$ s.t. both $x_1^j$ and $x_2^j$ are divisible by $3$ is r.v. $X$ and has binomial (why?) distribution $\mathcal B(n, p)$. Can you find it's parameters?

Analogously, number of $j$ s.t. both $x_3^j$ and $x_4^j$ are not divisible by $3$ has is $Y$ and has binomial distribution $\mathcal B(m, q)$.

Note that $X$ and $Y$ are independent (because $x_i^j$ are mutually independent, and $X$ is function of $x_1^j, x_2^j$ while $Y$ is function of $x_3^j, x_4^j$), so now the question is to find probability two independent variables with binomial distributions are the same.